# dot separator for numeration of cells in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA to generate summary of excel file. This summary has sections (n variable) and positions (x variable). I'm checking if cell is empty, if not I'm writting assiging its section/number so table would look like
1.1 text
1.2 text
...
1.10 text
and so. But when using code:

```
Offset(z, 0).Value = n & "." & x
```

I got 1,1 1,2 with coma instead of dot. How to force a dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case Excel perceives the dot as part of a number (decimal separator) and converts it to your system's default which is the comma. You need to force excel to treat the cell value as text.

Two options are the following:

`Offset(z, 0).Value = "'" & n & "." & x`

or

`Offset(z, 0) = "@"`
`Offset(z, 0).Value = n & "." & x`

The first one adds the single quote in front of the cell contents/value which causes Excel to treat these as text. The second one changes the cell format to text before changing its value.

Answer (score 0):

try `Offset(z, 0).value = n & chr(46) & x`

Comment: Nope, there's still coma